# Convert RTF to HTML in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, rtf

Is there a way to convert RichTextFormat to HTML in Javascript?

Iam trying to paste the RTF content copied , from clipboard iam getting the text/rtf content, now i need to show it with all styles applied in a div. how can i achive this ?? any suggestions?.

Eg:
 if i  copy

ghkasjhdk

**gjhgjh**

^^ this as RTF

i will get a string simmilar to this

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Calibri;}}
 {\*\generator Msftedit 5.41.21.2510;}\viewkind4\uc1\pard\sa200\sl276\slmult1\lang9\b\f0\fs40\par
 \b0\fs22 ghkasjhdk\par
 \b\fs40 gjhgjh}
```

i need this to be converted to html with `<strong>` tags and `<br>`'s respectively

Comment: *"Paste"* where ?

Comment: "Is there a way to convert RichTextFormat to HTML in Javascript?" — Lots of ways. If you want to do it yourself, start by learning how to write parsers, and then read the specification for the RTF format.

Comment: in content ediitable div

Comment: @Quentin ok, Where can i learn it ?? How should i start.

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=RTF+specification&t=hd&ia=web

Comment: @AmarnathRShenoy did you fix it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may wish to adapt this NodeJS package: [rtf2html](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rtf2html).
I understand this has already be done with an older version, as you can see [in this Github repository](https://github.com/Novlr/rtf2html).

After you get the corresponding HTML code, you can add it to your container using the usual DOM methods, or a library like jQuery if you are already using it.

Comment: Could the downvoter(s) please care to give their thoughts? I sincerely wish to learn to try to give a better answer next time. Thank you

Comment: Is there any another solution without using nodejs? I mean is there solution rtf to html in client side with pure javascript?

Comment: As far as I can remember, this solution has no NodeJS-specific dependencies, apart from being supplied in a npm package

Comment: this package fails to parse valid RTF files, IDK why