# Convert RTF format to HTML JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, rtf

Let`s say i have an Email, that i can save as *.rtf document, and this is what i would get inside of it

```
{\rtf1\ansi\deff0 {\fonttbl {\f0\froman Times;} {\f1\fmodern Courier New;} {\f2\fswiss Arial;} } {\stylesheet {\snext0 Normal;} {\*\cs1 \additive Default Paragraph Font;} {\*\cs2 \additive ...
```

Now i want to transform this rtf into html and render on my web page using react (or pure javascript, doesnt really matter). Are there any tools that could help me with this? Or how do i even convert it like that?

I need to do it on FrontEnd

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert RTF to HTML in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42783781/convert-rtf-to-html-in-javascript)

Comment: @hgb123 i checked this post already. 
As i see, it should be used on backend, with nodejs + there are no tutorials at all. not sure i can use it

Comment: Hi @WhoAmI , did you find any solution?

Comment: @vahidsamimi no.

Comment: You don't need node.js to use that library, the first section on this page https://github.com/tbluemel/rtf.js/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md shows you how to use it with vanilla javascript.