# Cant get data from API when using richtextbox on web - ASP.NET Core Web API in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

I has an error when get data from API after using `System.Windows.Forms` to call `RichTextbox`. API is not responding, even though debugging shows not error. If I don't call the richtextbox, I can get data normally.

This is my code:

```
string rtfString={\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\froman\fprq2\fcharset0 Times New Roman;}}
\viewkind4\uc1\pard\sa160\sl252\slmult1\lang1066\f0\fs26 - \tab G\'e3y 1/3 gi\u7919?a x\u432?\u417?ng \u273?\'f2n (P).\fs28\par
\pard\fs24\par
}

RichTextBox rtBox = new RichTextBox();

if (rtfString == null)
{
    return new JsonResult("null");
}

if (rtfString.StartsWith("{\\rtf1"))
{
    rtBox.Rtf = rtfString;
}

return new JsonResult(rtBox.Text);
```

My config

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <RootNamespace>PatientResult_API</RootNamespace>
    <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Thank you so much

Comment: Why are you creating a rich textbox in your API ?!? Makes no sense at all - the API should **only** return data - handling GUI elements like a rich textbox should be left to the caller / client - that's not the job of the API itself ..

Comment: Oh, because i want convert rtf format to string then transmisson in API, if this way is not possible you can suggest me to convert rtf to string on javascript?

Comment: I suggest you could try to follow this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42784073/7609093) to convert the rtf to string by using the js package.